# Use the same currency as the credit card

Tags: stripe-payments

I am working on an application where payments are handled by stripe. Customers are from 2 different countries.
stripe.js is used on the client side. stripe-php library is used on the back-end to charge the customer after stripe.js posts to the back-end page.
Is there a way to detect the country of the card the customer is using so that I can use the corresponding currency in the back-end call charging the customer?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a card's country of issue from a Stripe token response that comes from Stripe.js or Checkout. In addition to the token id this includes a card object with the properties like the card brand and country.

When you call `stripe.createToken` take a look at the token object in the response, e.g. `result.token.card.country`

The token object also contains a "client_ip" property that can be helpful for deciding if you want to process a charge given a particular IP address / locale derived from that. https://stripe.com/docs/api#token_object

Beyond trying to determine locale from card data or ip address, you could simply ask the user which currency they would like to be billed in, giving some additional flexiblity

Comment: The charge request is sent from php in my case but your answered my question by mentioning this is possible. I tested the php data and the country is there. Thanks